# Meaning of Pump Max Lift

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps

I am looking at grabbing a small submersible pump to recirculate some cleaning solution in a toilet for about 24 hours or and I was looking at the following pump.  The spec says max lift 3'.  Now my education tell me that if the outflow pipe is 100% full and other idealized conditions the only part that matters is the difference between the intake and discharge elevations.  So in theory as long as my discharge end is lower then 3' from the pump I will be just fine.

My question is, is the max lift height basically the height of a standing column of water the pump would sustain, or is it the point where the pump losses its specified flow rate?

[image]